# Leaflet embedded video not showing up

Tags: php, html, ajax, leaflet

I am trying to display a video inside a marker on the map for a specific city. I have a back end that makes returns the URL for the specified city but when I use a video embedded I get a CORS error, the solution I found was to use the html they provide, however it does not seem to want to render on the marker.

```
//=============================ADD LIVE FEED=============================//
function getLiveFeed(isoCode) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "source/php/getLiveFeed.php",
    type: `GET`,
    dataType: `json`,
    data: {
      isoCode: isoCode,
    },
    success: (result) => {
      result["webcams"].forEach((el) => {
        let html = `
          <p>${el["name"]}</p>
          <a name="windy-webcam-timelapse-player" data-id="${el["id"]}" data-play="day" href="https://windy.com/webcams/${el["id"]}" target="_blank"></a>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://webcams.windy.com/webcams/public/embed/script/player.js"></script>
        `;
        addIcon(el["coords"], html, false);
      });
      console.log(result);
    },

    error: (xhr) => {
      console.log(xhr["responseText"]);
    },
  });
}

//=============================ADD ICONS=============================//
function addIcon(coords, html, type) {
  const icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: type
      ? "/vendors/leaflet/images/marker-icon.png"
      : "/vendors/leaflet/images/customMarkers/pin.png",
    iconSize: [15, 25],
  });

  L.marker(coords, { icon: icon }).bindPopup(html).addTo(map);
}
```

FAQ:

- Does the PHP return without errors ? Yes it does
- Does the embedded element render in html? Yes it does
- Have you tried using the link inside the video src attribute? Yes I have I still get a CORS error
- The getLIveFeed uses this API: https://api.windy.com/api/webcams/v2/
- The html that is being rendered is from here: https://www.windy.com/-Embed-widget-on-page/widgets?51.544,-0.173,5

Comment: Is there any documentation for that player script you are using there?

Comment: There is : https://api.windy.com/webcams/docs

Comment: That appears to be API documentation, I don’t see it mentioning the script you are using in there.

Comment: That is correct because the script is the embedded element they provide on the website. I will update the question to make it clearer, apologies for the misunderstanding.